# How are Vince and Drama exactly related?

Tags: entourage

In the TV series [Entourage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entourage_%28TV_series%29), we know that Vince & Johnny Drama are half brothers, but it is not clear that whether they have same mother or same father.

According to Wikipedia there are certain instances in the TV show which indicate that the exact relation between Vince & Drama is not clear, for example - Vince and Drama share the same last name.

They appear to have the same mother in the episode "Aquamom" when Johnny calls himself her "first born". However, Drama calls Vincent's mother "your mom" in the episode "My Maserati Does 185".

I guess the fans know more details and we can have more inputs on this topic to determine how Vince and Drama are actually related. How are Vince and Drama exactly related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes from the show indicates that they are, just like you said, half-brothers. But, whether they have the same mother, or father is unclear.

The following quote by "Drama" implies that they have the same father

> You have **your** mom's legs but I got dad's calves

However, in the first episode of the third season when their *(?)* mother is hugging Vince, "Drama" says

> Always hugs him first... I am your firstborn!

...which implies the opposite.

No definite answer has been provided in the show, and, as far as I know, no producer or actor have commented on it either.

The character bios on the official site at HBO says that they are **brothers**, though. Not half-brothers. So, even though the show is a little fuzzy when it comes to how these two are related, I would go with "full brothers".

Comment: It doesn't imply that she's both their moms. It implies that she likes Vince more than her own flesh and blood imho.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that they are from the same dad, but Vincent's mom raised them both. Thus, Johnny is just referring to himself as her "first born" beacuse he's older. Regarding their dad as far as their genetics, it was made clear they weren't full blood to say the least.